# How does the Pokemon HeartGold / SoulSilver Safari Zone work?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver

At serebii.net I read that some Pokemon show themselves in the safari zone with certain types of blocks, but it does not really say if blocks will stay, how they level, or that switching out will clear the items. I also says that some Pokemon will only appear after a certain number of days. Are these days counting from the start of my game? or the start of the required blocks?

Also, I noticed that I can place 'other' items. What is the use of these items? Should I even place them in my Safari Zone?

Can someone explain to me the fundamentals to the safari zone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bulbapedia's](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Johto_Safari_Zone) pretty good on this, but I'll try to answer some of your questions here. When you switch blocks they'll stay like that until you switch them again. They 'level' by keeping that block out for 10 days, and some Pokemon only appear when you put certain objects/blocks of certain levels into the Safari Zone.